# Are there any drawing options that control how SKNodes are displayed when scaled?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios8

Here's an example of artifact that I have an issue with (picture hopefully worth a thousand words -- I've scaled both images to make the detail more apparent):

64x64 native iOS crop (using setScale(2.0)) scaled to 128x128 using nearest neighbour in external application:

[image: 64x64 native iOS crop (using setScale(2.0)) scaled to 128x128 using nearest neighbour in external application]

64x64 crop scaled to 128x128 using nearest neighbour in external application, the rotation is applied before the scale transform:

[image: 64x64 crop scaled to 128x128 using nearest neighbour in external application:]

From the images, the first is the undesirable and the second is what I'd like. The first shows the "scaled pixels" are rotated. In my case (even though the pixel is actually a block of pixels), I want the rotation to happen before the scaling has happened (if there was some way to affect the order of the transformations).

I'm basically trying to get a chunkier/pixellated look (common enough), but I want all translations to sit on this new pixel grid (rotations are especially ugly). I've seen some applications do this, are they just creating their own game engine? or am I missing something in SpriteKit?

I think I got all the details required, if I missed any, ask.

Comment: If have to reference the docs, but what you're asking is totally available in spritkit

Comment: I have access to the docs, is that what you're asking? I don't exactly know what I'm looking for -- I've looked for order of transforms and anything that might affect setScale of the nodes.

Comment: I think what @TheGamingArt is talking about is the filteringMode property of SKTexture. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKTexture/filteringMode

Comment: Oh that's not the issue at all (as displayed in both cropped images). They both have "hard" edges -- neither have been anti-aliased. What's happening (that I don't want) is the rotation is applied *after* the pixels have been scaled up.

Comment: I don't think the rendering engine works in the way you want. You can verify this by explicitly testing out what you want by applying scaling after rotation.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I have to reference the docs. In CALayer stuff, I know you can choose how to adjust the scaling rendering via view.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest;. I'm pretty sure I've seen similar stuff for SpriteKit, but I have to look at the docs when I have some time.

Comment: I also think you may want to look through this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=9271

Comment: Sorry @TheGamingArt, that is not the issue that I have presented.

Comment: I know what you're referencing, sorry, was just pointing out some information on SpriteKit works in it's respective sampling type and order when resizing and adjusting rendering.

Comment: I appreciate it. I also tried adjusting the scene's scale as well but that didn't work either. :/